# Toolbox controls not active in VS2008

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-5.0

i install Visual studio 2008 and install windows mobile 5.0 pocket pc SDK
to create my own app and deploy it but when i create new project the toolbox controls
are not active i don't what is the problem can any one help me???

Comment: Can you see the controls in the toolbox? Are they just grayed out? Or are there no controls at all?

Comment: I think that the problem in windows mobile 5.0 pocket pc it doesnot install its controls.

Comment: yes i see them but they are grayed out

Comment: Dear Dirk Strauss do you know the problem ??  i see them but they are grayed out

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Step 1: Right click on the toolbox
Step 2: Click on "Choose Items" from the context menu
Step 3: From the 'Choose Toolbox Items" select the controls you want.

The controls will then be added to your toolbox.

EDIT:
You can also change your Target Platform. Check that yours is Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK. If not, right click on your Project Name (not the solution) and from the context menu, select the "Change Target Platform" menu item. Change your target platform from that screen that pops up.

I hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately the first method doesnot work no new controls added to toolbox.yes the target platform is windows mobile 5.0 i don't know what is the problem??